# RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (549) must match the size of tensor b (512) at non-singleton dimension 1

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

```
GLUE_TASKS = ["cola", "mnli", "mnli-mm", "mrpc", "qnli", "qqp", "rte", "sst2", "stsb", "wnli"]

#useful in preprocessing, this sets what each task does. 
task_to_keys = {
    "cola": ("sentence", None),
    "mnli": ("premise", "hypothesis"),
    "mnli-mm": ("premise", "hypothesis"),
    "mrpc": ("sentence1", "sentence2"),
    "qnli": ("question", "sentence"),
    "qqp": ("question1", "question2"),
    "rte": ("sentence1", "sentence2"),
    "sst2": ("sentence", None),
    "stsb": ("sentence1", "sentence2"),
    "wnli": ("sentence1", "sentence2"),
}

def set_module_grad_status(module, flag=False):
    if isinstance(module, list):
        for m in module:
            set_module_grad_status(m, flag)
    else:
        for p in module.parameters():
            p.requires_grad = flag

def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
    predictions, labels = eval_pred
    if task != "stsb":
        predictions = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
    else:
        predictions = predictions[:, 0]
    return metric.compute(predictions=predictions, references=labels)

#setting some model parameters
task = "qnli"
sentence1_key, sentence2_key = task_to_keys[task]
# model_checkpoint = "test-glue/basemodel"

num_labels = 3 if task.startswith("mnli") else 1 if task=="stsb" else 2

metric_name = "pearson" if task == "stsb" else "matthews_correlation" if task == "cola" else "accuracy"
validation_key = "validation_mismatched" if task == "mnli-mm" else "validation_matched" if task == "mnli" else "validation"

model_checkpoint = "google/mobilebert-uncased"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint, use_fast=True)
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint, num_labels=num_labels)
model = model.to(device)

args = TrainingArguments(
    "test-glue",
    evaluation_strategy = "epoch",
    learning_rate=2e-5,
    per_device_train_batch_size=batch_size,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=batch_size,
    num_train_epochs=epochs,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    save_steps=0
    # load_best_model_at_end=True,
    # metric_for_best_model=metric_name,
)

#load dataset
actual_task = "mnli" if task == "mnli-mm" else task #some error checking.. 
dataset = load_dataset("glue", actual_task)
metric = load_metric('glue', actual_task)

# tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint, use_fast=True)
def preprocess_function(examples):
    if sentence2_key is None:
        return tokenizer(examples[sentence1_key], truncation=True)
    return tokenizer(examples[sentence1_key], examples[sentence2_key], truncation=True)
encoded_dataset = dataset.map(preprocess_function, batched=True)


trainer = Trainer(
    model,
    args,
    train_dataset=encoded_dataset["train"],
    eval_dataset=encoded_dataset[validation_key],
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics
)
trainer.train()
```

I not quite sure why I am getting the error "RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (549) must match the size of tensor b (512) at non-singleton dimension 1" at the like "trainer.train()". Like isn't the each sample supposed to be consistently size of 512. This only happens with MobileBERT model and not on DistilBERT model. The code that I am using is mostly based on  the huggingface colab tutorial https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/notebooks/blob/master/examples/text_classification.ipynb#scrollTo=7k8ge1L1IrJk

Comment: Please post the full error stacktrace.

Comment: This is the full error I am getting